# find gsm modem com port using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how to find gsm modem com port using vb.net? i writing this code :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Form1
'connect your mobile/GSM modem to PC,
'then go in device manager and check under ports which COM port has been slected
'if say com1 is there then put com2 in following statement
Dim SMSEngine As New SMSCOMMS("COM5")
Dim i As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    SMSEngine.Open() 'open the port
    SMSEngine.SendSMS() 'send the SMS

End Sub
End Class
Public Class SMSCOMMS
Private WithEvents SMSPort As SerialPort
Private SMSThread As Thread
Private ReadThread As Thread
Shared _Continue As Boolean = False
Shared _ContSMS As Boolean = False
Private _Wait As Boolean = False
Shared _ReadPort As Boolean = False
Public Event Sending(ByVal Done As Boolean)
Public Event DataReceived(ByVal Message As String)

Public Sub New(ByRef COMMPORT As String)
    'initialize all values
    SMSPort = New SerialPort
    With SMSPort
        .PortName = COMMPORT
        .BaudRate = 19200
        .Parity = Parity.None
        .DataBits = 8
        .StopBits = StopBits.One
        .Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
        .DtrEnable = True
        .RtsEnable = True
        .NewLine = vbCrLf
    End With
End Sub
Public Function SendSMS() As Boolean
    If SMSPort.IsOpen = True Then
        'sending AT commands
        SMSPort.WriteLine("AT")
        SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf) 'set command message format to text mode(1)
        SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=""+628988397877""" & vbCrLf) ' enter the mobile number whom you want to send the SMS
        _ContSMS = False
        SMSPort.WriteLine("SUCCESS" & vbCrLf & Chr(26)) 'SMS sending
        SMSPort.Close()
    End If
End Function

Public Sub Open()
    If Not (SMSPort.IsOpen = True) Then
        SMSPort.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Close()
    If SMSPort.IsOpen = True Then
        SMSPort.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

but in this code :

```
Dim SMSEngine As New SMSCOMMS("COM5")
```

i need to know which com port that my modem gsm was connected, so i need code that can automatically find com port, can someone help me please?

**thank you very much.** 
nb : i use visual basic 2012 (vb.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like others said, you will have to loop all ports and check whether you can connect use Rate/port to connect to the GSM modem. Here is a library, it is c#, but you can download the source code to see how it works.

http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm

Comment: check the link I posted, it has the source code. although it is in c#, it is straightforward to convert to vb.net. however, it uses a different library to check the connection. the library itself works fine and you donot need do any low level coding.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this automatically without having to either select the COM port in your program interface or hard code the port number is to attempt to open all available COM ports, and send each one some kind of status command and listen (with a short timeout period) for a reply that only the GSM modem would return. Of course, this means you may send weird commands to other serial devices, if any, that are attached to the computer, but I'm guessing in your case it will be the only serial port with anything attached.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx) for the function to get the list of serial port names on the current computer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you make more simple and efficient? can we know which port that used by gsm modem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Code to Find Attached modems and their Attributes in vb.net.

```
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
                    "root\CIMV2", _
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem")
                ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
                For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
                    If queryObj("Status") = "OK" Then
                        modems = queryObj("Description")
                        baud = queryObj("MaxBaudRateToSerialPort")
                        Port = queryObj("AttachedTo")
                         da.rows.add(1)
                        da.rows(incount).item(1)=Port 
                        da.rows(incount).item(2)=baud
                        ComboBox1.Items.Add(modems)
                        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.FindString("Nokia")
                        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "" Then
                            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.FindString("Samsung")
                            If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "" Then
                                ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                 intcount+=1
                Next
```

You need to add reference to the System.management assembly and also import the namespace system.management.